# Disable WooCommerce product unless time criteria is met

Tags: php, wordpress, time, woocommerce

How would I disable certain WooCommerce products by category unless the time is between 11:15am and 3:30pm for example?
I also want this to reoccur everyday. I was thinking about somehow setting the in stock attribute to false, however, I am not sure how to accomplish this.

I have searched this online and I only found plugins that could restrict items per day, not during a specific time period.

I am new to WooCommerce so any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I am looking for a code solution because I could not find a plugin to meet my needs. However, if someone knows a plugin that can accomplish this, please let me know.

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin or for a code solution? You could filter the products by adding an action to woocommerce_product_query and if they are in the category and its not within the time period, don't show them.

Comment: A code solution - I'll update my question